# ¿Para que seriven los indices planos Laravel?

Tags: laravel, migration

para que me sirven o de que manera puedo usar los **indice planos** en Laravel , me encontre estos en la documentacion de laravel

```
$table->index('state');             Agrega un índice plano.
```

y no se para que me sirve exactamente o de que manera pueso usarlo.

Comment: Es una forma que ofrece Laravel para poder indicar que la columna (`state`) será un campo indexado dentro de la tabla que estás creando a través de tu migración.

Es decir tener esto

    `$table->index('state');`

Es lo mismo que si en tu tabla directo en tu gestor de base de datos tuvieras

    `INDEX(state),`

Comment: Ahora comprender que un índice es un puntero a una columna específica de nuestra tabla en la base de datos, hecho generalmente por que esta columna será utilizada para búsqueda de información con lo cual se ayuda al gestor de bases de datos a acelerar dicho proceso.

Comment: Ahora esto es un tema mas de bases de datos, que de Laravel en si, por lo cual te recomiendo leer al respecto en la [doc oficial de mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html)

Comment: Entonces si **state** fueran una llave foránea  podría ser un campo indexado